# Inheriting the styles from the parent, but my custom css is having no effect

Tags: wordpress

My themes correctly inheriting the styles from the parent, but my custom css is having no effect.

I have created a new folder in my wp-content/themes folder named `twentyten-child.

I have created a file called `functions.php` which contains:

```
<?php
/**
 * Loads the parent stylesheet.
 */
function load_parent_stylesheet() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_parent_stylesheet' );
?>
```

I also created a file inside named `style.css` which contains:

```
/*
Theme Name: Twentyten Child
Theme URI: https://p4002720.scm.tees.ac.uk/thetreasurechestWP/
Description: This is a aged, weathered, worn and nostalgic style theme
Author: Michael Barley
Author URI: https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100008253000376
Template: twentyten
Version: 0.1
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/
body {
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: Have you activated the child Theme?

Comment: Yeah, `Twentyten Child` is active @Blackbam

Comment: Have you followed all the instructions from the codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes ?

Answer (score 0):

You have only included the parent CSS dependency, you also have to include the child theme CSS, as explained in the Codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

   $parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

   wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
   wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
      get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
      array( $parent_style ),
      wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
   );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```